# Not able to open website on localhost, handler mapping is missing

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

When ever I try to open wordpress website on my localhost I get below error.

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

1. I have tried enabling HTTP activation but that did not work.
2. I have installed PHP for IIS from microsoft web PI, that did not work.
3. I think there is handler mapping missing, I am not able to map handle.

Comment: This is what I use for development, you can run it off a flash drive, you can even set it up where you can change PHP version with a dropdown list, supper simple to use. http://www.uniformserver.com/

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix It worked ! Thaanks

Answer (score 0):

install [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or xaamp and start php and mysql Service.

create a folder for example "site".

Copy all worpress folder and file in to www/site in wamp server

and enter the "localhost/site" in the browser and install wordpress quiqly.

soon wordpress goto run

Answer (score 0):

Go and download the WAMP http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Its a set for web developers, that includes php, apache and mysql.

You can se localhost to act as a real webserver, you can find online many tutorials and how to